# Title need to be unique based upon the grade and subject

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Title need to be unique based upon the grade and subject.
I need to add like this

```
grade   subject     title
2       english     abc
2       english     abc    -> need validation error
3       english     abc    -> no validation error
```

How would I do this validation in larevels?

I did this

```
'title'=>'required|unique:titles,title',
```

In here title coloumn  become unique but not consider the subject and grade.

```
grade   subject     title
2       english     abc
2       english     abc    -> get validation error
3       english     abc    -> get validation error
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
    'title' => 'unique:titles,title,NULL,id,grade,'. $grade
    ]);

    //
}
```

You've to pass `$grade` also to the validator.

This check should work. This rule checks if the `title` is unique by combining the `title` and `grade`.

If it's `'title' => 'unique:titles,title,NULL,grade, 3`

It gives the exception for the grade 3.

Comment: In here i get error when im trying add same title for grade 3...but i need to add that title to grade 3.because title should be unique based on grade.like composite key(title+grade)